# Fbx Import Glitch?

Tags: import, error, .fbx

Im trying to import this fbx model of a soldier, no errors come up when its loading but this is what i get when it opens. [image: Glitched Mesh[1]]

Comment: I would have to see your blend file to be sure, but when I've seen that sort of thing before, it was often because scale had not been applied properly.